# D3.js axis tick label rotation based on width of label and bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I've encountered an issue with the length of axis tick labels. For example I would like to rotate my x-axis tick labels when the label is wider than the bar which it represents. I am using different data sets so would like this behavior as the number of bars and label widths will change.

Is there a way to find the length of a string in D3 in order to compare with the width of bar?
I did see a general suggestion of finding string sizes using the span tag however I dont think that this is an option for D3.

The code snippet below shows what I would like to do on a very basic level.
**Please NOTE**: the code in the snippet is not mine, its is code I found online in order to get a quick example for the issue representation.

```js
// https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018/#technology-most-loved-dreaded-and-wanted-languages
    const sample = [
      {
        language: 'This text should be rotated',
        value: 78.9,
        color: '#000000'
      },
      {
        language: 'Python',
        value: 68.0,
        color: '#fbcb39'
      },
      {
        language: 'Go',
        value: 65.6,
        color: '#65cedb'
      },
      {
        language: 'JavaScript',
        value: 61.9,
        color: '#f9de3f'
      },
    ];

    const svg = d3.select('svg');
    const svgContainer = d3.select('#container');
    
    const margin = 80;
    const width = 1000 - 2 * margin;
    const height = 600 - 2 * margin;

    const chart = svg.append('g')
      .attr('transform', `translate(${margin}, ${margin})`);

    const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
      .range([0, width])
      .domain(sample.map((s) => s.language))
      .padding(0.4)
    
    const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .range([height, 0])
      .domain([0, 100]);

    // vertical grid lines
    // const makeXLines = () => d3.axisBottom()
    //   .scale(xScale)

    const makeYLines = () => d3.axisLeft()
      .scale(yScale)

    chart.append('g')
      .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
      .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));

    chart.append('g')
      .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

    // vertical grid lines
    // chart.append('g')
    //   .attr('class', 'grid')
    //   .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
    //   .call(makeXLines()
    //     .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
    //     .tickFormat('')
    //   )

    chart.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'grid')
      .call(makeYLines()
        .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
        .tickFormat('')
      )

    const barGroups = chart.selectAll()
      .data(sample)
      .enter()
      .append('g')

    barGroups
      .append('rect')
      .attr('class', 'bar')
      .attr('x', (g) => xScale(g.language))
      .attr('y', (g) => yScale(g.value))
      .attr('height', (g) => height - yScale(g.value))
      .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
      .on('mouseenter', function (actual, i) {
        d3.selectAll('.value')
          .attr('opacity', 0)

        d3.select(this)
          .transition()
          .duration(300)
          .attr('opacity', 0.6)
          .attr('x', (a) => xScale(a.language) - 5)
          .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth() + 10)

        const y = yScale(actual.value)

        line = chart.append('line')
          .attr('id', 'limit')
          .attr('x1', 0)
          .attr('y1', y)
          .attr('x2', width)
          .attr('y2', y)

        barGroups.append('text')
          .attr('class', 'divergence')
          .attr('x', (a) => xScale(a.language) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2)
          .attr('y', (a) => yScale(a.value) + 30)
          .attr('fill', 'white')
          .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
          .text((a, idx) => {
            const divergence = (a.value - actual.value).toFixed(1)
            
            let text = ''
            if (divergence > 0) text += '+'
            text += `${divergence}%`

            return idx !== i ? text : '';
          })

      })
      .on('mouseleave', function () {
        d3.selectAll('.value')
          .attr('opacity', 1)

        d3.select(this)
          .transition()
          .duration(300)
          .attr('opacity', 1)
          .attr('x', (a) => xScale(a.language))
          .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())

        chart.selectAll('#limit').remove()
        chart.selectAll('.divergence').remove()
      })

    barGroups 
      .append('text')
      .attr('class', 'value')
      .attr('x', (a) => xScale(a.language) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2)
      .attr('y', (a) => yScale(a.value) + 30)
      .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .text((a) => `${a.value}%`)
    
    svg
      .append('text')
      .attr('class', 'label')
      .attr('x', -(height / 2) - margin)
      .attr('y', margin / 2.4)
      .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
      .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .text('Love meter (%)')

    svg.append('text')
      .attr('class', 'label')
      .attr('x', width / 2 + margin)
      .attr('y', height + margin * 1.7)
      .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .text('Languages')

    svg.append('text')
      .attr('class', 'title')
      .attr('x', width / 2 + margin)
      .attr('y', 40)
      .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .text('Example')

    svg.append('text')
      .attr('class', 'source')
      .attr('x', width - margin / 2)
      .attr('y', height + margin * 1.7)
      .attr('text-anchor', 'start')
      .text('')
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

div#layout {
  text-align: center;
}

div#container {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #2F4A6D;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.bar {
  fill: #80cbc4;
}

text {
  font-size: 12px;
  fill: #fff;
}

path {
  stroke: gray;
}

line {
  stroke: gray;
}

line#limit {
  stroke: #FED966;
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke-dasharray: 3 6;
}

.grid path {
  stroke-width: 0;
}

.grid .tick line {
  stroke: #9FAAAE;
  stroke-opacity: 0.3;
}

text.divergence {
  font-size: 14px;
  fill: #2F4A6D;
}

text.value {
  font-size: 14px;
}

text.title {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

text.label {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

text.source {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
  <title>Bar chart with D3.js</title>
  
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='layout'>
    <!-- <h2>Bar chart example</h2> -->
    <div id='container'>
      <svg />
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Or if someone knows an efficient way to add span to axis tick titles that would also be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the important bits. You can tweak to your liking

```
    chart.append('g')
      .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
      .classed('axis', true) // class the x axis for selection
      .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));


    d3.select('.axis')
        .selectAll('text') // select all the text elements 
        .each(function(d){ 
           if(this.getBBox().width > 50) { // getBBox gets bouinding box info on svg elements
            d3.select(this).attr('transform','rotate(45)')
           .style('text-anchor','start')
        }})
```

Comment: Thank you @SmokeyShakers, I have a new issue related to this solution now. I am trying to create an array containing all the lengths of the x axis but I cant seem to get it working.
I have tried the following 
`svg.selectAll("text")
.each(function(d){ wordArray.push(this.getBBox().width)})
`
However as you can guess this gets all the text, not just the text from the x-axis, is there a way to target the x-axis only?

Comment: Yes, in my example, when I first append the x-axis I give it the class, axis. This allows me to select with `select('.axis').selectAll('text')`